# Creating a button Template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, button, text

I'm trying to create a template for a button that I can use over and over again on a form.

The `Button`, I want it to contain a `Grid` with two rows and a custom piece of text within the bottom row.

This is what I've got so far, but I don't think it's right because I want to set the text from within the button element.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
    <Grid Width="444">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="51" />
            <RowDefinition Height="36" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#286c97"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#5898c0">
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then to call the template I was hoping I could go:

```
<Button Content="This is the text" />
```

But sadly this doesn't work.  Is there some other template that I'm supposed to be using to pass the text value to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, there is a control called `ContentPresenter`. Place that inside your template wherever you want it to be. But remember, that it could be anything, a text, an image or a bunch of other controls, and your `Button` nor your ControlTemplate, should not care about what it is.

```
ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
    <Grid Width="444">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="51" />
            <RowDefinition Height="36" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#286c97"></Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#5898c0">
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `ContentPresenter`, when used inside a `ContentControl`, like the button, automatically attaches to the `Content`, `ContentTemplate` and `ContentTemplateSelector` properties of the templated parent.

Now if you want to display more than just Text, or want to customize the text more, just pass a `DataTemplate` as your `ContentTemplate` directly to the specific button.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myButtonContentTemplate">
    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myButtonContentTemplate}"/>
```